# How to have Type safe and compiler checked Enums in Scala

Tags: scala, enums, shapeless, scala-cats

I saw several questions on SO regarding this issue, but still couldn't find a really good answer:

I would like to have a `State Enum`, with 3 states: `Good`, `NotGood`, and `Unknown`.

Until now, no big deal. But since the state comes from an external API (not documented, that's why the `Unknown` state), it comes using snake case, so I do a `findByName` transformation:

```
object State extends Enumeration {
  val Good = Value("good")
  val NotGood = Value("not_good")
  val Unknown = Value("unknown") // "unknown" ??

  def findByName(name: String): State.Value = {
    Try(State.withName(name)).getOrElse {
      Logger.warn(s"Found unexpected result: $name")
      Unknown
    }
  }
}
```

Now, there are two problems:

- 1st: I would like the compiler to warn me about non-exhaustive matches. This can be achieved using sealed traits, which leads me to my second problem
- 2nd: In the case of the `Unknown` I would like to save the value received, but `Enums` get the name on definition, and not on construction. But if I have a sealed trait, just like [this tutorial](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html) how could I define such scenario?

I got something like:

```
sealed abstract class State(val name: String)

case object Good extends State("good")
case object NotGood extends State("not_good")
case object Unknown extends State("unknown")
```

Still, the `unknown` is hardcoded, and I would like for it to be an argument/constructor parameter.

Also, I lost the `findByname` property...

> While I prefer a solution using 'pure' Scala, would also like to see some solution with Shapeless or Cats

Comment: maybe there's some lib that can do this? I bet there are shapeless and cats solutions, and I've no problems in recurring to them (although my lack of experience using them), but a solution without recurring to them would be preferable if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a class for the Unknown case:

```
case class Unknown(value: String) extends State("unknown")
...
def findByName (name: String) = name match {
  case "good" -> Good
  case "not_good" -> NotGood
  case x -> Unknown(x) 
}
```